# SHQueryRecycleBin Not Working on .net Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have Methods Out of which : 1 Use *"SHQueryRecycleBin"* to Query Recycle Bin & Other Use *"SHEmptyRecycleBin"* To Delete Recycle Bin, Both of em Works Fine without any issue on my *.Net 4.8* Projects.

But While i am trying to use the same code on *.Net Core 3.1* *"SHQueryRecycleBin"* Simply Refuse To Work & Throw *"HRESULT -2147024809"*.

To Check I Tried it on {.Net 4.8} vs {.Net Core 3.1} Console, WinForm & Wpf App & it worked Everytime on .net Framework.

Code Sample :

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern int SHQueryRecycleBin(string pszRootPath, ref 
SHQUERYRBINFO  pSHQueryRBInfo);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)] // also tried pack=4 
public struct SHQUERYRBINFO
{
    public int  cbSize;
    public ulong i64Size;
    public ulong i64NumItems;
}

public static int GetCount()
{
    SHQUERYRBINFO sqrbi = new SHQUERYRBINFO();
    sqrbi.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SHQUERYRBINFO));
    int hresult = SHQueryRecycleBin(string.Empty, ref sqrbi);
    return (int)sqrbi.i64NumItems;
}
```

Comment: It's going to be quite difficult to get help without providing the source code that is being used to make the Win32 call.  Why not add it to the question to assist others in debugging the issue?

Comment: Thanks Martin, i've added code sample now :)

Comment: Thanks for adding that. I can reproduce this issue myself and am just investigating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an inkling as to what the problem might be before I tried your code.

If you run your code as is, you receive a `HRESULT` of `-2147024809` from `SHQueryRecycleBin`.

This is actually a `HRESULT` of `0x80070057`, which is the error `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` (or '*The parameter is incorrect*' if you prefer plain English).  This indicates that there is an issue with one or more of the parameters being sent to the Win32 call.

In the case of your code, the culprit is your `StructLayout` declaration of `SHQUERYRBINFO`.  You have defined a `Pack` alignment size of 1 (and tried 4), but are using `ulong`s in the `struct`.  A Win32 `ulong` is 8 bytes, so you should use `8` as the `Pack` size in .Net Core:

```
...

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]
public struct SHQUERYRBINFO
{
    ...
```

Incidentally, if you omit the `Pack` parameter completely, the default value of 8 will be used.

Comment: Thanks for the Response, I Can Access Recycle Bin Now After Changing Pack to 8 :)

Sounds like a Silly Mistake From My End haha.